# Скрытное управление звуком

Tags: c#, аудио

Нашёл следующий код(рабочий, проверял):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace volume_controller
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
        private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Mute()
        {
            SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
                (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
        }
        private void VolDown()
        {
            SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
                (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
        }
        private void VolUp()
        {
            SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
                (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
        }  
    }
}
```

При управление звуком таким образом, во время изменения показывается это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно управлять звуком так, чтобы не отображалась эта шкала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На дынный момент нашёл это: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40361942
В принципе вариант мне подходит, громкость изменяется скрытно.

Инструкция по установке: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio
Страница либы: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio/3.0.0.1